# Replace a character with #(hash symble) only in 5th & 6th field

Tags: perl, replace, awk

I am trying to Replace a character with #(hash symble)  only in 5th & 6th field.
eg. I have to replace 'Z' with '#' only in 5th & 6th field (using perl or AWK script). And remaining fields containng 'Z' symbol should not be affected.

(just I'm updating the post to replace double quote(") instead of Z by #. Can I achive this? thanks for precious help)
eg: i/p file:

```
aa",bb,ccc,ddd,eee",ddd",fff
aa1",ba1,ccc1,"ddd1,eee"1,ddd1,fff1
z,aa2,bb2",ccc2,ddd2","eee2",ddd2,fff2"
```

Expected O/p file:

```
aa",bb,ccc,ddd,eee#,ddd#,fff
aa1",ba1,ccc1,#ddd1,eee#1,ddd1,fff1
aa2,bb2",ccc2,ddd2#,#eee2#,ddd2,fff2"
```

Thanks.

Comment: With SED I can replace first occurence of Z

Comment: This is trivial to do in awk, using the `sub` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its only two filed, loop can be omitted.

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{gsub(/Z/,"#",$5);gsub(/Z/,"#",$6)} 1' file
x,aaZ,bb,ccc,ddd,eee#,dddZ,fff
y,aa1Z,ba1,ccc1,#ddd1,eee#1,ddd1,fff1
z,aa2,bb2Z,ccc2,ddd2#,#eee2,ddd2,fff2Z
```

To replace `"` in fifth and sixth field:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{gsub(/\"/,"#",$5);gsub(/\"/,"#",$6)} 1' file
aa",bb,ccc,ddd,eee#,ddd#,fff
aa1",ba1,ccc1,"ddd1,eee#1,ddd1,fff1
z,aa2,bb2",ccc2,ddd2#,#eee2#,ddd2,fff2"
```

Comment: Yeah but the result is the same length as the loop (once you use the same FS/OFS init syntax and remove optional white space) and the loop has no redundancy (e.g. if you decide to change "Z"s to "@" instead of "#"s) and lets you extend the solution to more fields so while it's not a big deal either way I favor using a loop as it has some functional advantages.

Comment: @Jotne  Can I replace double quote(") instead of Z with #

Comment: @Raj Yes.  If you update your original post with example, I can show you how.

Comment: @Raj It does.  Se output of my code with your data. It replace `"` inf field `5,6` with  `#`.  `eee"` changes to `eee#`.  You misses the  `z` on line three.

Comment: @Jotne  friend, it is not replacing 5th & 6th field in any record. I dont know, how you are getting correct result, I wonder friend!

Comment: @Raj Then your data is not the same as you post.  I just copy and past.  What is the output of: `awk -F, '{print $5,$6}' file`.  It should be `eee" ddd"`, `eee"1 ddd1` and  `ddd2" "eee2"`.  I guess you are not testing data in your post, but real data.

Comment: @Jotne it is working when I used original posted data. But I dont know whey it was working for simillar data. Any way, Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=5;i<=6;i++) gsub(/Z/,"#",$i)} 1' file
x,aaZ,bb,ccc,ddd,eee#,dddZ,fff
y,aa1Z,ba1,ccc1,#ddd1,eee#1,ddd1,fff1
z,aa2,bb2Z,ccc2,ddd2#,#eee2,ddd2,fff2Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Perl way to do the job:

```
perl -anF, -e '$"=","; s/Z/#/ for (@F)[4,5];print"@F";' < in1.txt
```

If you have mutiple `Z` in a field, you could use:

```
perl -anF, -e '$"=","; s/Z/#/g for (@F)[4,5];print"@F";' < in1.txt
```

**Output:**

```
aaZ,bb,ccc,ddd,eee#,ddd#,fff
aa1Z,ba1,ccc1,Zddd1,eee#1,ddd1,fff1
aa2,bb2Z,ccc2,ddd2Z,#eee2,ddd2,fff2Z
```

**Edit according to comment:**

*in1.txt*

```
aa",bb,ccc,ddd,eee",ddd",fff
aa1",ba1,ccc1,"ddd1,eee"1,ddd1,fff1
aa2,bb2",ccc2,ddd2","eee2,ddd2,fff2"
```

*Command:*

```
perl -anF'','' -e '$"=",";s/"/#/ for (@F)[4,5];print"@F";' < in1.txt
```

*result:*

```
aa",bb,ccc,ddd,eee#,ddd#,fff
aa1",ba1,ccc1,"ddd1,eee#1,ddd1,fff1
aa2,bb2",ccc2,ddd2",#eee2,ddd2,fff2"
```

Comment: As far as we know there may be multiple `Z` characters in a field, so you need `s/Z/#/g` or `tr/Z/#/`.

Comment: @Borodin: May be, it isn't said in question. Edited answer to take this into account.

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE  thanks for your answer!  Can I replace double quote(") instead of Z with #

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE  I tried:
 perl -anF, -e '$"=","; s/"/#/g for (@F)[4,5];print"@F";' < in1.txt  and
perl -anF, -e '$"=","; s/\"/#/g for (@F)[4,5];print"@F";' < in1.txt 
no luck!!

Comment: @Raj: Sure, you can replace `Z` by `"`, see my edit. It works fine, what problem have you encountered?

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE,  thanks you very much. It's working perfect. Sorry for bothering you.  thanks a lot friend again!!